# Y axis movement interfering with X axis movement

Tags: java, collision

I'm writing a game and I'm currently working on collisions. I have the following code:

```
    if(y + dy + h > o.getY() && y + dy + h < o.getY() + o.getH()
            && x + dx + w > o.getX() && x + dx < o.getX() + o.getW()){
        dy = o.getY() - y - h;
    }else if(y + dy > o.getY() && y + dy < o.getY() + o.getH()
            && x + dx + w > o.getX() && x + dx < o.getX() + o.getW()){
        dy = y - o.getY() - o.getH();
    }
    if(x + dx + w > o.getX() && x + dx + w < o.getX() + o.getW()
            && y + dy + h > o.getY() && y + dy < o.getY() + o.getH()){
        dx = o.getX() - x - w;
    }else if(x + dx > o.getX() && x + dx < o.getX() + o.getW()
            && y + dy + h > o.getY() && y + dy < o.getY() + o.getH()){
        dx = o.getX() + o.getW() - x;
    }
```

o is an obstacle

- o.getY() returns the y coordinate of the obstacle
- o.getX() returns the x coordinate of the obstacle
- o.getW() returns the width of the obstacle
- o.getH() returns the height of the obstacle

x is the x coordinate of the player
y is the y coordinate of the player
w is the width of the player
h is the height of the player
dx is the change in x for the next frame
dy is the change in y for the next frame

The code for the y axis doesn't work quite right and I commented it out to try something new, but what I found was when I changed the code to this:

```
    /*if(y + dy + h > o.getY() && y + dy + h < o.getY() + o.getH()
            && x + dx + w > o.getX() && x + dx < o.getX() + o.getW()){
        dy = o.getY() - y - h;
    }else if(y + dy > o.getY() && y + dy < o.getY() + o.getH()
            && x + dx + w > o.getX() && x + dx < o.getX() + o.getW()){
        dy = y - o.getY() - o.getH();
    }*/
    if(x + dx + w > o.getX() && x + dx + w < o.getX() + o.getW()
            && y + dy + h > o.getY() && y + dy < o.getY() + o.getH()){
        dx = o.getX() - x - w;
    }else if(x + dx > o.getX() && x + dx < o.getX() + o.getW()
            && y + dy + h > o.getY() && y + dy < o.getY() + o.getH()){
        dx = o.getX() + o.getW() - x;
    }
```

It ended up throwing the player to the right side of the screen. I have no clue why.

Comment: Might just be me, but I find it hard to parse what your program does without more code.

Comment: Essentially, it checks if the player will be inside of the obstacle in the next frame. If so, then it changes the dy or dx variable so that when added to x or y it will place the player next to the obstacle instead of inside it.

Comment: It's still difficult to know what's wrong. When you call o.getY(), at what point of the obstacle is it recording the co-ordinate? Does that point make a difference for the different expressions?